# Plotly R: Hovertext for values which have 0 y-axis values

Tags: r, plotly

**Problem:** In plotly, is there a possibility to get the hoverinfo also for values which have zero y-value? So, in the example below, I want to have hovertext for xaxis value `a, d` and `e`.

Any suggestions?

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)

dt <- data.table(
  x = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
  y = c(0 , 5, 2, 0, 0),
  z = c(12, 14, 19, 23, 0)
)

plot_ly(dt,
        x = ~x) %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~y,
           text = ~paste("y-Values:", y, " z-Values:", z),
           hoverinfo = "text")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution (add in layout `hovermode = 'x'`):

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)

dt <- data.table(
  x = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
  y = c(0 , 5, 2, 0, 0),
  z = c(12, 14, 19, 23, 0)
)

plot_ly(dt,
        x = ~x) %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~y,
           text = ~paste("y-Values:", y, " z-Values:", z),
           hoverinfo = "text") %>% 
  layout(hovermode = 'x')
```